# Mongoose query not working as expected

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to use mongoose to query a collection by some field and its getting 0 results always.

This is the query

```
Users.find({"role":3}).exec((err,users) => {
    if(err){
        logger.error(properties.get("500.logging.getUsers"));
        logger.error(err);
        res.status(500).send({message:properties.get("http.response.500")});
      }else{
        if(!users){
          res.status(404).send({message:properties.get("users.response.404")});
        }else{
          res.status(200).send({users:users});
        }
      }
    });
```

And querying by mongo compass Im getting results

[image]

I also tried to put the role and 3 without quotes without success

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advise

Comment: try `Users.count()`, if it returns 0 too, you might be running your queries on the wrong collection... check your `Users` config

Comment: if I query without params I get all the documents, so I think is the correct collection

Comment: Can you update your question to include your schema definition for `Users`?

Comment: Yep, thx @JohnnyHK I have string type for app_role in schema and is number on mongodb. Now its working! Post an answer with this and I will accept it as correct answer if you want ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose will cast your query values based on the type of each field as defined in the model's schema. So because you're defining `role` as a string in your schema, the `3` in your query gets cast to `'3'` and the documents with `role: 3` aren't matched.